# how to sync contents of two text boxes in html ??

Tags: html, angularjs

I have two textboxes which I want to keep synchronized i.e. the content of both the textboxes should be exactly same. If one textbox changes the other textbox content should be synchronized automatically and viceversa..

Comment: Please add more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In angularjs it is super easy

```
<input type=text ng-model='prop'>
<input type=text ng-model='prop'>
```

bind to same scope property.

Answer (score -1):

I think this should do the trick using jquery:

```
$("#textbox1").blur(function() {
  $("#textbox2").val($("#textbox1").val());
});

$("#textbox2").blur(function() {
  $("#textbox1").val($("#textbox2").val());
});
```

Comment: since we talk about angular framework, you need to use one of its basic capabilities ,the binding feature and not JQuery DOM manipulation.

Answer (score -1):

assuming your next question (that got rejected) is related to this original question there is a pure javascript solution...

assuming you have control over javascript on both pages and can make sure one page opens the other (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open) so you can keep a window reference

```
var theOtherWindow = window.open(pageurl, 'newwindow');
```

you can then use postMessage (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) to transfer instructions.

let's say you have an input field named 'bob' on both pages you could do something like (I'll use jquery for brevity)

```
<input type="text" name="bob"></input>

<script>
    // send message on change
    $('input[name=bob]').on( 'change', bobchange );
    function bobchange(){
        var theMessage = ([
            'updateInput',
            'bob',
            $('input[name=bob]').value();
        ]).join('::');
        theOtherWindow.postMessage(theMessage);
    }

    // receive message
    $(window).on('message', function(e){
        if(e.origin !== 'http://example.com:8080') return; // minimal security
        theMessage = e.data.split('::');
        switch(theMessage[0]){
            case 'updateInput':
                $('input[name='+theMessage[1]+']')
                    .off('change') // prevent infinite loop
                    .value(theMessage[2]) // update field
                    .on( 'change', bobchange ); // restore event
            break;
        }
    });
</script>
```